# Can someone point me to a really easy to understand guide to web.config?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I'm really interested in gaining an in-depth understanding of the format and structure of the web.config file for ASP.NET web development. I'd like to know if there's some really easy to comprehend material (apart from the MSDN docs) which can provide me a ground-up understanding of the web.config file and its different sections.

Any suggestions?

Comment: After you've read the MSDN docs, what exactly is still confusing you?

Comment: @rball... u should point it as an answer, with the msdn link, so other people searching for web.config docs find it quickly

Comment: I think it's a valid question.  The MSDN docs are technical in nature and don't flow as a "tutorial" of sorts like many are used to (from reading blogs). I have found that with the Web.Config, its tricks and quirks (like, for example putting connection strings in separate files and using the configSource to separate test and live environments) are things you pick up from a variety of sources. The MSDN resource is exhaustive, but doesn't really go into things like "You should do this because of ____" type scenarios.

Comment: @Atomiton: Thanks for explaining in more detail. 
@rball: That's exactly what I'm looking for. Things like best practices gleaned by developers over the years. I'd refer to MSDN docs to get the syntax, but only after I've determined what tags to use. To me the latter is posing a something of a challenge.

Comment: I don't think you'll find a comprehensive list. But the links I provided have been helpful for me.

Comment: Later question which is possible duplicate: [What is a good resource for understanding web.config in asp.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3462972/1497596)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a really good article:

- [The Web.Config Demystified](http://www.sitepoint.com/article/web-config-file-demystified/)

It takes the magic out of the Web.Config... which after all is just an XML file.

- [Best Practices on using App Settings and Connection Strings](http://peterkellner.net/2008/02/23/webconfigbestpractice/)
- Another link about [putting AppSettings in a separate File](http://www.odetocode.com/Articles/345.aspx). I do this ALL THE TIME. I'll have several files where my test environment are different and have something like:

> Conn.test.Config
>
> Conn.test.Config
>
> App.test.Config
>
> App.live.Config

- Here's MSDN docs which outline the [additions for .Net 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178683.aspx).
- AND... one GREAT way of finding out what people have found to be useful is the items [tagged Web.Config in delicious](http://delicious.com/tag/Web.Config)

I also love showing people that the fancy "website configuration" under the ASP.Net Tab in IIS is just parsing an XML file and there's nothing fancy about it.