# What is a good resource for understanding web.config in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-config

I modify web.config when I *HAVE TO* :-)  Debugging setting, session state setting, etc.  But in those cases, some tutorial or error message has been explicit: "Open web.config and do XYZ".

What I wonder is, what else can it do?  What things that I do now in other ways would be better done in web.config.  Is there a good primer or even a comprehensive web.config book or other resource that I can study to get good understanding of what it is really capable of?

I've searched for "web.config" on amazon, etc., and lots of returns for specific technologies that use it, but nothing focused solely on web.config itself.

I hope this isn't a really dumb question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622302/net-understanding-web-config-in-asp-net.

Comment: THanks @kbrimington.  I saw that one -- MSDN is good, for sure -- but not everything I needed.  Mostly, I'm interested not just in *how* to customize web.config, but when and why it makes sense to put some setting there, instead of other normal places like code-behind or separate classes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Can someone point me to a really easy to understand guide to web.config?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/952222/1497596)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start with [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719558.aspx)

http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/web-config-file-demystified

Scott Hanselman has some good postings too:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ManagingMultipleConfigurationFileEnvironmentsWithPreBuildEvents.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the info -- the sitepoint article is good.  I still wish I had some kind of "cookbook" showcasing creative uses folks have put the web.config file to, or even some kind of higher-level piece about what web.config is best put to use for (and what it shouldn't be used for).  I get bits and pieces from blogs, etc., so I guess for now that will have to do until someone writes "Web.Config Unleashed", or some such.  :-)

Answer (score 4):

check the below links...

[ASP.NET Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719558.aspx)

[Format of ASP.NET Configuration Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ackhksh7%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

[Web.config Tutorial ASP.Net 2.0 & 3.5](http://24x7aspnet.blogspot.com/2009/04/webconfig-tutorial.html)

[ASP.NET Tutorial: Web.Config](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/miscellaneous/article.php/c17407)

[Managing Multiple Configuration File Environments with Pre-Build Events](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ManagingMultipleConfigurationFileEnvironmentsWithPreBuildEvents.aspx)

[The ASP.NET Web.config File Demystified](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/web-config-file-demystified)

Comment: Wow -- I had no idea something like 'web.config transformation' was a part of VS2010.  My stingy boss is just going to have to fess up some cash for the upgrade.  That's awesome!